# jqtscroll - How do I send the scroll content to the end of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

How do I send the scroll content to the end of the page?
There's a bind event to do this?

http://code.google.com/p/jqtscroll/

Answer (score 0):

the awswer:

```
scrollEnd: function scrollEnd(){
    var x = -Math.round(this._scrollMin.e);
    var y = -Math.round(this._scrollMin.f);
    return this.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

in the jqt.scroll.js file.